# Accessing object details in PHP thru global variables

Tags: php, object

I am new to PHP from the .net world and this is the code that i have,

```
 class A 
    {
       Album $album; // In C# .net i could have done this and assigned the display       action album data to this          

       public function displayAction()
    {
        $form = new ButtonForm();

        $id = (int)$this->params('id');
        if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array('action'=>'add'));
        }
        $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);

        return array(
            'id' => $id,
            'album' => $album,
            'form' => $form
        );
    }

    }
```

How can i do this is PHP ? 
Consider that i come a pure object oriented technology. So help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you want actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can do type hinting in function arguments, but I am thinking that you can't with field variables of a class.  Instead of `Album $album;` use `public $album;`.  Then you can access it freely outside the object.  e.g.

```
$obj = new A(); 
echo $obj->album;
```

Keep in mind though your var must be declared `public` to access it this way.  `private` and `protected` will not allow access in the global scope.  You will need to create accessor functions in that case.

**EDIT**

Also, whenever accessing field variables **within** your class use the `$this` keyword.  So again, instead of `$album` you use `$this->album`.